# PHP if() evaluation problem needs a rewrite

Tags: php

I noticed  this weird evaluation yesterday after searching for a few hours in my code for an error. i am passing scores into php, sometimes the score=0  which causes an issue.

send php          ?blah=blah&score=0

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['score']){
    //do database update stuff
}else{
   // show entire webpage
}
```

It works great unless the score=0 the if() will evaluate to false and return the entire webpage to my ajax handler and error. I have temporarily changed !empty to isset but this will cause problems in the future because isset evaluates to true even if the score key is in the url string without a value.
ex: (?blah=blah&score=&something=else)

my question is: what is the best way to recode this to work correctly now and in the future?

edit: there are a few working answers here, i appreciate everyones time. it was difficult to choose an answer

Comment: try using `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: You might want to use `strlen()` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['score']) && ($_REQUEST['score'] !== '')) {
 ...
}
```

The isset will handle the presence/absence of the query parameter, and the strict string (!==) comparison will handle the case where the 'score' query is present but has no value. PHP treats all data coming from _GET/_POST/_REQUEST as strings, so this test is 100% reliable.

Comment: selected this one because although it does not expand on what i am doing like some of the other answers do, it does answer my question exactly.   thank you

Answer (score 3):

As the [manual](http://php.net/empty) says, a variable is considered `empty()` if it has an empty **or zero** value.

So it will treat your variable wrongly as empty even though `0` is a perfectly acceptable value in your case.

If you need `score` to be a number, you could use `isset()` in combination with a [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) check instead:

```
if((isset($_REQUEST['score']) and (is_numeric($_REQUEST['score'])){
```

Check out the manual page to see the kinds of values `is_numeric()` accepts. If `score` is always an integer, you can also use `is_int((int)$_REQUEST['score'])` but that will convert invalid input values to `0`.

Additionally, as @sightofnick says, it's better to use explicit `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

**Re your update:**

In that case I would

1. Do  check whether the variable is `"0"` (string "zero")
2. If it is `"0"`, make it `0` (integer "zero")
3. If it is not `0`, convert it to an integer `(int)$_REQUEST["score"])`
4. If the conversion resulted in `0`, it was invalid input - exit
5. You have a valid integer variable.

Comment: I just explained why i cannot use isset.. i dont think you read the entire question.

Comment: @Johnny fair enough, added more accurate alternative

Comment: I appreciate the well explained answer. unfortunitely is_numeric can also allow letters mixed in with numbers which will cause me huge problems

Comment: @Johnny  I added some pseudo-code for the next step. (But I agree Marc's answer answers the exact question perfectly.)

Comment: Thank you Pekka. that would perfectly make sure that the score is a number. i will do that. again, i appreciate the time you put into this.

Answer (score 2):

empty() will return `false` if a value is zero. Use [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php) or [array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php) instead, if you want to check if a variable in an array is set:

```
if (array_key_exists('score', $_REQUEST)) {...}
```

Comment: i liked this one, unfortunitelly i can change 'score' to 'anything' and it still returns true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['score']) && $_REQUEST['score'] != ''){
    //do database update stuff
}else{
   // show entire webpage
}
```

Comment: != '' will fail . 0 and '' are equivalent to each and PHP happily converts between them as necessary. It should be !==

Comment: Not one to argue, but actually you are flat out wrong here my friend - take my above code and plug it into PHP if you don't believe me- just did it myself and it worked as expected.  Furthermore, !== '' doesn't even make sense, !==  means "does not evaluate to", so you are essentially saying "if $_REQUEST['score'] does not evaluate to false", which will always be true if $_REQUEST['score'] isset.

Comment: Tried to edit my comment but missed the window - looks like both of our solutions work.  I'm assuming the reason mine works as well is because technically the $_REQUEST value of 0 is getting passed in as a string and not an integer 0 value, hence the reason why PHP isn't automatically converting it to be equivalent to ''

Comment: Everything coming out of the get/post/result/cookie superglobals is a string. Try: `var_dump('' == 0); var_dump('' === 0)` sometime.

Comment: Ok so basically you're confirming **exactly** what I just said.  Did you plugin my code, or are you again making false assumptions?  Try var_dump('0'=='') .  Again while var_dump('' == 0) is true, var_dump(''=='0') is not because 0 is being evaluated as a string instead of a number.  Thanks again for proving why my solution works and why you were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve that with

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['score']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['score'])) {}
```

That of course if scrore can only contain numeric value